# loop using javascript and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, loops

Two loops are existed here, the custom-maker works but the on-click function does not,the on-click changes all of 'mkrclick' which does not change mkrclick0 by clicking custom-maker0 and so on, do someone can teach me and solve the problem? I would thank to the guys very much.

```
<script>
angular.module('ngMap').run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.mouseover = function() {
console.log('mouseover', this);
this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
};
$rootScope.mouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = '#FEF9E7';
};

$rootScope.click = function() {
for ( var e=0; e < map_data.length; e++) {
document.getElementById('mkrclick'+e).innerHTML = "<div>Paragraph          changed!</div>";}};

$rootScope.customMarkers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < map_data.length; i++) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers.push({
    address: map_data[i].work_address,
    "class": "my1",
    content: map_data[i].work_address,
    content_1: map_data[i].job_reward,
    idnum: 'mkrclick'+ i
    });
  }
  });
  </script>




    <custom-marker ng-repeat="cm in customMarkers" position="         {{cm.address}}"
      on-mouseover="mouseover()" on-mouseout="mouseout()"
      on-click="click()">

<div ng-repeat="cm in customMarkers" id='{{cm.idnum}}' class="padrep">
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `cm` into the `click()` function then use the properties of that marker object to do what is needed

```
on-click="click(cm)"

$rootScope.click = function(cm) {
      document.getElementById(cm.idnum).innerHTML = 'TEST';
}
```

Comment: It said 'SyntaxError: Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference.'

Comment: soon, it said  null is not an object .

Comment: which map module are you using? Provide link to the docs. Also a live plunker demo would help

Comment: https://ngmap.github.io/#/!custom-marker-two-way-binding.html, I am running this one but want to click that button to innerHTML a div

Comment: as you know, button1 demonstrates div1 and so on, thank you again to take a look of my trouble.

Comment: ok change to `$rootScope.click = function(evt,cm)` .. first argument is the event object. Just tested it here http://plnkr.co/edit/iEyYNhcrsmX36yDQgGVp?p=preview

Comment: Sorry my stupidity, I want to change the div1 by clicking the marker1 to innerHTML info1, 2 be 2 and 2 and so on, does it need any loop?http://plnkr.co/edit/NYwEQeG1doYtHqGjsfhU?p=preview

Comment: somethink like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/lomEBd6q8QXTkXbD6FOl?p=preview

Comment: yes! and I want to innerHTML with specific content, not No to Yes, maybe <div id='div1'>1234</div> ->after clicking marker 1 -> <div>5678</div>

Comment: all depends on source of that data

Comment: and <div id='div2'>2468 -> after clicking marker 2 -> <div>1357</div>

Comment: can you use the cm.address as example? thank you for your time again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [] | range:100">
//do stuff
</div>
```